# Embedding "Rich Text Editor" in a web view

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview, ckeditor

Now, I'm trying to embed "[CKEditor](http://cksource.com/)" (Rich Text Editor) in my application.

"ckEditor" folder *with all js and plugins* is located inside "asset" folder".

My problem is: output supposed to be like that

[image: The output is supposed to be like that]
In my case the output is like that :
[image: In my case the output is like]

My Code is like :

- 1- Main Activity:

  package com.example.webviewtest;

  @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
      WebView webView;
      TextView myTextView;

  ```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
      webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
      webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
      WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
      webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
      webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
      webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
      webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
      webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
      webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
      webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
      webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
      webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/ckeditor/index.html");

  }
  ```

  }

  - With other Editors *not CK Editor*  the page is being displayed successfully but the  "editable text area" is being displayed as an image, no edits or selections are allowed.

I don't know the source of my problem, but , i think it's "JS" Issue...Any help..?!!

**- Update**

I uploaded the ckEditor folder on remote host, and i still get the same image "above" not only on my application but also in the browser..!!!!!!

:

Answer (score 0):

After some navigation through CKEditor page, I found that the editor is not enabled to be compatible with Android devices, however, you can manually enables it for your android devices under your own risk, to do so, you need to edit the "core/env.js" file and enable "search for white list".

Comment: or u can also set     CKEDITOR.env.isCompatible = true; Source http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_unsupported_environments